# How to add a className to the first item on load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, classname

This function produces a list when loaded to the DOM. But I need to add another classname "active" to the first item on the list after it was loaded.
Given the function:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

function Menu(props) {
    const list = props.list
    const [active, setActive] = useState(null)
    const menuItems = list.map((list, index) => {
        return <li className={`items ${active === index ? 'active' : ''}`} key={index} onClick{() => setActive(index)}><Link>{list}</Link></li>
    })
    return (
        <ul>{menuItems}</ul>
    )
}
```

After the DOM was loaded, it should look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li className="items active"><a href="/">list1</a></li>
    <li className="items"><a href="/">list2</a></li>
    <li className="items"><a href="/">list3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thank you for the solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `null` as the start value of `active`. The parameter that the function [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) receives is in fact the default (start) value:

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(0); // <-- set to 0

const menuItems = list.map((list, index) => (
  <li className={`items ${active === index ? 'active' : ''}`} ...
))
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but

```js
function Menu(props) {
    const list = props.list
    const menuItems = list.map((list, index) => {
        return <li className={`items ${index === 0 ? 'active' : ''}`} key={index}>{list}</li>
    })
    return (
        <ul>{menuItems}</ul>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hello my friend. It's useful but things have changed when I decided to add a click event.  See, after I click, that item should have the class name "active" and the previous item will have be stripped off of that "active" class